# How to get all sub matrices of 2D array without numpy?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, matrix, submatrix

I need to get all submatrices of the 2D array and to do the manipulation for each submatrix. So I created example matrix:

```
M3 = [list(range(5)) for i in range(6)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I need to capture 3 rows and 3 columns and then shift this "window" till I get all submatrices. The first submatrix would be:

```
 [[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2]]
```

and the last one is:

```
 [[2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4]]
```

For this matrix I need 12 submatrices. However, I become more using code with which I tried to solve the problem:

```
for j in range(len(M3[0])-3):
   for i in range(len(M3)-3):
       for row in M3[0+j:3+j]:
           X_i_j = [row[0+i:3+i] for row in M3[0+j:3+j]]
           print(X_i_j)
```

I get 18 but not 12 (with two duplicates of each submatrix):

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
...
[[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
[[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

And with this sample of code I get 6 submatrices with 1 duplicate for each:

```
for i in range(len(M3)-3):
   for j in range(len(M3[0])-3):
       X_i_j = [row[0+i:3+i] for row in M3[0+j:3+j]]
       print(X_i_j)
```

I do not see what is wrong with it and why I get the duplicates. How can I get all sub matrices of 2D array without numpy for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working ( with change of order of vars and constants ):

```
for j in range(len(M3)-2):
   for i in range(len(M3[0])-2):
      X_i_j = [row[0+i:3+i] for row in M3[0+j:3+j]]
      print('=======')
      for x in X_i_j:
         print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it slightly different.
a function to read y-number-of-rows
then a function to read x-number-of-columns from those rows, which then is your sub.

This would work for any (2D) array / sub-array

Sample:

```
def read_y_rows(array, rows, offset):
    return array[offset:rows + offset]


def read_x_cols(array, cols, offset):
    return list(row[offset:cols + offset] for row in array)


def get_sub_arrays(array, x_dim_cols, y_dim_rows):
    """
    get 2D sub arrays by x_dim columns and y_dim rows
    from 2D array (list of lists)
    """
    result = []
    for start_row in range(len(array) - y_dim_rows + 1):
        y_rows = read_y_rows(array, y_dim_rows, start_row)
        for start_col in range(len(max(array, key=len)) - x_dim_cols + 1):
            x_columns = read_x_cols(y_rows, x_dim_cols, start_col)
            result.append(x_columns)
    return result
```

to use it you could do:

```
M3 = [list(range(5)) for i in range(6)]
sub_arrays = get_sub_arrays(M3, 3, 3) ## this would also work for 2x2 arrays
```

the `sub_arrays` is again a list of lists, containing all found subarrays, you could print them like this:

```
for sub_array in sub_arrays:
    print()
    for row in sub_array:
        print(row)
```

I know it is a lot more code than above, just wanted to share this code.